# how to download any file from the web using asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html

there is something I am trying to do , 
I want to automatically download some specific files that are stored in
the internet , such as photos videos images etc.
and then store them.

some photos , I am able to download by graphic interface,
but I want automation - downloading whatever I want whenever I want 
through a very specific process which i'll determine later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx) object to download a file in a simple way:

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);     
Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + Application.StartupPath);
```